# XPath: Browsing table hierarchy by column

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml structure that describes a simple table with (x*2) rows and always 2 columns (in the following example x=1 for simplicity):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    1
    </td>
    <td>
    2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    3
    </td>
    <td>
    4
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I would like to browse this hierarchy with XPath expressions in the following order:

```
1-3-2-4
```

In access notation:

> row[1]::column[1] -> row[2]::column[1] -> row[1]::column[2] -> row[2]::column[2]

How can I do this with XPath expressions?

I am doing all this inside of Schema ST4 but I welcome answers of raw xpath expressions as well, as I am pretty much stuck.

FYI, I am coming from a C++ background so my thoughts were that I must be able to use an iterator (xsl:iterate) that iterates through the according rows/columns however until now I couldn't make this work. But I am pretty new to XPath so I am probably lacking the comprehension to derive this myself.

My xsl iterator selects each odd  row (i.e. 1,3,5..) with

> tr[position() mod 2 = 1]

This works fine. Then I thought another iterator inside of the iterator would allow me to iterate through each of that row's  columns (1,2,3..). That probably works but how do I get the equivalent column of the **next** row from there?

Does this make sense XPath wise or do I have to attack this from a different angle?

Comment: Can you use xpath 2.0? If so, I think the expression you want is `//tr/td[1],//tr/td[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention `xsl:iterate` (which is part of XSLT 3) so I assume you can use XSLT 2 or 3 and there I think the general task of processing/outputting the cells column wise can be done with positional grouping:

```
  <xsl:template match="table">
      <xsl:variable name="cols" select="count(tr[1]/td)"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="tr/td" group-by="position() mod $cols">
          <xsl:sequence select="current-group()!normalize-space()"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38YV

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Works like a breeze and is straightforward to understand for me.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately this doesn't work if (x > 1). E.g. xml looks like this:<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    1
    </td>
    <td>
    2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    3
    </td>
    <td>
    4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    5
    </td>
    <td>
    6
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    7
    </td>
    <td>
    8
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: Sorry, explaining it again. The xml has two more rows with 5-8. The output is then 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 8 however what I want is 1 3 2 4 5 7 6 8. But Still I accept your answer because my question did not make this clear in the first place!